# Bootstrap validator marks entire form in red even when some fields are correct

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to build a long form that is validated with BootstrapValidator which I am very new at.

My biggest issue is that if one field is incorrect it marks ALL of the fields with the red coloring even if the success check marks stay. The form submits properly but the visual validation is what seems very off.
To see the form in action.... You can really see the issue if you click submit with nothing filled in, then proceed to fill it in correctly.
http://chelseaporter.com/APSoPC/adoptForm3.php
Here is a snippet of my HTML code and my javascript.
THANKS ALL!

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="address">Street Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Your Street Address">
    </div>
    </div>

 <!--many more fields)-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div><!-- closes panel Body-->
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var validator = $("#adoption-form").bootstrapValidator({
    //live: 'disabled',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok",
        invalid: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove", 
        validating: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
    }, 
    fields : {
        name :{
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Please provide your name."
                }, 
                stringLength: {
                    min : 4, 
                    max: 35,
                    message: "Name must be between 4 and 35 characters long"
                },
            }//end validators
        },  
        email :{
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Please provide an email address"
                },
                regexp: {
                        regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
                        message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
                }
            }//end validators
        },  
        address : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Address is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        city : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "City is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        state : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "State is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        zip : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Zip is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        years : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Years at current address is required"
                },
                numeric : {
                    message: "Valid number of years lived at current address is required (only numbers)"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        hPhone : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Home phone is required. If you only have one phone please enter that number for Home Phone AND Alt Phone."
                },
                phone : {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: "Valid phone number is required (only numbers)"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        altPhone : {
            validators : {
                phone : {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: "Valid phone number is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        dNumber : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Driver's License number is required"
                },
                numeric : {
                    message: "Valid Driver's License number is required (only numbers)"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        dState : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Driver's License state is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        ePhone : {
            validators : {
                phone : {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: "Valid phone number is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        hType : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Home Type required."
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        hStatus : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Home Status Required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        lNumber : {
            validators : {
                phone : {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: "Valid phone number is required"
                }
            }//end validators
        },
        student : {
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message: "Please answer if you are a student."
                }
            }//end validators
        },


    } //end ALL validators  
});

    validator.on("success.form.bv", function (e) {
         if (data.fv.getInvalidFields().length > 0) {    // There is invalid field
            data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#adoption-form").addClass("hidden");
        $("#confirmation").removeClass("hidden");

         var $form = $(e.target),
                            fv    = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');           
});

//process the form
$("#adoption-form").submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'address'           : $('input[name=address]').val(),
                    'city'                  : $('input[name=city]').val(),
                    'state'                 : $('select[name=state]').val(),
                    'zip'                   : $('input[name=zip]').val(),
                    'years'             : $('input[name=years]').val(),
                    'hPhone'            : $('input[name=hPhone]').val(),
                    'altPhone'          : $('input[name=altPhone]').val(),
                    'dNumber'           : $('input[name=dNumber]').val(),
                    'dState'            : $('input[name=dState]').val(),
                    'employer'          : $('input[name=employer]').val(),
                    'ePhone'            : $('input[name=ePhone]').val(),
                    'hType'             : $('select[name=hType]').val(),
                    'hStatus'           : $('select[name=hStatus]').val(),
                    'lName'             : $('input[name=lName]').val(),
                    'LNumber'           : $('input[name=LNumber]').val(),
                    'student'           : $('select[name=student]').val(),
                    'sName'             : $('input[name=sName]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode          : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 
                            console.log(formData);

                });
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
            console.log(formData);
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the validation is working as expected. Your form elements have the "has-success" class on them but is being over-written by the "has-error" class. Which is confusing because none of the parent elements have the "has-error" class. It looks like it's properly adding the "has-success" class on ONLY the elements that are complete. Put an important on your "has-success" class color so it looks like this:

```
.has-success{
      color: #3c763d !important; }
```

You will be overwriting BS code with this, but I find it odd it's not styling it properly in the first place. Also, it looks like your "Alternate Phone" field is showing as complete without anything in it. Though, it may be technically correct as it might not be a required field, could the "complete" in this context has a different meaning than the other "complete's" which is poor UX.

Let me know if that important worked.

Comment: I just updated the CSS. You can see it at the site here. http://chelseaporter.com/APSoPC/adoptForm3.php   unfortunately it appears to not fix the issue ;( I see what you said about the alt phone. I'll worry about that once I get this other fixed! You are right in that the alt phone isn't required which is why it's getting the complete check.

Comment: Hmm.. Now it doesn't have the "has-success" class. Let me go over your stuff again. Give me a minute here...

Comment: Oh. It looks like you have a form-group wrapping your entire form, too. Inside your panel panel-default and just above your <form> element, you have a "form-group" class (among others) on a div. You can probably just remove that entire <div> element and all its contents. Don't forget to remove it's closing div, too.

Comment: If I could buy you the dinner of your choice it would be yours! I've spent an embarrassing amount of time on this. I <3 you!

Comment: Haha we've all been there. I'm glad I could help.