# Ajax form submit + Bootstrap validator was working. Now "data is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Back during the summer I spent several pain staking weeks trying to figure out bootstrap validator PLUS ajax submitting of forms. I finally got it working and just left the form unfinished for a while.

I tested the form three days ago and it worked just fine. I moved some files around but nothing that I thought had to do with the form and now it's suddenly not working. I don't remember changing anything with the form files at all. In fact I have a link to when I was working on this form before from stackoverflow and you can see that my JS hasn't changed!

[Bootstrap validator marks entire form in red even when some fields are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616819/bootstrap-validator-marks-entire-form-in-red-even-when-some-fields-are-correct)

After the fields are validated and you submit I now get "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" This was working fine just a few days ago!

I'm pretty sure I have several issues in the JS code but I'm not sure where to start to fix the issue. I think I have some redundancies as well...

Here is a link to my site with the form. From there you can test it and see the data error I'm getting. Currently the only required field is Name just to speed along testing.

http://www.chelseaporter.com/APSoPC/adoptForm.php

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var validator = $("#adoption-form").bootstrapValidator({
    //live: 'disabled',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok",
        invalid: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove", 
        validating: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
    }, 
    fields : {
        name :{
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Please provide your name."
                }, 
                stringLength: {
                    min : 4, 
                    max: 35,
                    message: "Name must be between 4 and 35 characters long"
                },
            }//end validators
        },  
        email :{
            validators : {
                notEmpty : {
                    message : "Please provide an email address"
                },
                regexp: {
                        regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
                        message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
                }
            }//end validators
        },  

        //LOTS MORE VALIDATORS IN HERE

    } //end ALL validators  
});

    validator.on("success.form.bv", function (e) {
         if (data.fv.getInvalidFields().length > 0) {    // There is invalid field
            data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#adoption-form").addClass("hidden");
        $("#confirmation").removeClass("hidden");

         var $form = $(e.target),
                            fv    = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');           
});

//process the form
$("#adoption-form").submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'address'           : $('input[name=address]').val(),
                    'city'                  : $('input[name=city]').val(),
                    'state'                 : $('select[name=state]').val(),
                    'zip'                   : $('input[name=zip]').val(),
                    'years'             : $('input[name=years]').val(),
                    'hPhone'            : $('input[name=hPhone]').val(),
                    'altPhone'          : $('input[name=altPhone]').val(),
                    'dNumber'           : $('input[name=dNumber]').val(),
                    'dState'            : $('input[name=dState]').val(),
                    'employer'          : $('input[name=employer]').val(),
                    'ePhone'            : $('input[name=ePhone]').val(),
                    'hType'             : $('select[name=hType]').val(),
                    'hStatus'           : $('select[name=hStatus]').val(),
                    'lName'             : $('input[name=lName]').val(),
                    'LNumber'           : $('input[name=LNumber]').val(),
                    'student'           : $('select[name=student]').val(),
                    'sName'             : $('input[name=sName]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode          : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 
                            console.log(formData);

                });
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
            console.log(formData);
}); 

});
```

Process.php Code

```
            <?php
            // process.php

            $errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
            $data           = array();      // array to pass back data
            $body = implode("\n", $array);

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $state= $_POST['state'];
            $zip = $_POST['zip'];
            $years = $_POST['years'];
            $hPhone = $_POST['hPhone'];
            $altPhone = $_POST['altPhone'];
            $dState = $_POST['dState'];
            $dNumber = $_POST['dNumber'];
            $employer = $_POST['employer'];
            $ePhone = $_POST['ePhone'];
            $hType = $_POST['hType'];
            $hStatus = $_POST['hStatus'];
            $lName = $_POST['lName'];
            $lNumber = $_POST['lNumber'];
            $student = $_POST['student'];
            $sName = $_POST['sName'];
            //(!empty($_POST['student']) ? $_POST['student'] : null);


            $to = 'mekeri@gmail.com';
            $subject = "$name has sent you a message";
            $from = "AdoptionApp";

            //HTML headers for email
            $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            //begin of HTML message 
            $message = <<<EOF
                    <html>
                        <body bgcolor="#99CCCC">
                            <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
                                <tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>$name</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>$email</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Address</strong> </td><td>$address</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>City:</strong> </td><td>$city</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>State:</strong> </td><td>$state</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Zip:</strong> </td><td>$zip</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Years @ Address:</strong> </td><td>$years</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Home Phone:</strong> </td><td>$hPhone</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Alternate Phone:</strong> </td><td>$altPhone</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Driver License Number:</strong> </td><td>$dNumber</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Driver License State:</strong> </td><td>$dState</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Employer:</strong> </td><td>$employer</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Employer Phone:</strong> </td><td>$ePhone</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Type of home</strong> </td><td>$hType</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Home Status</strong> </td><td>$hStatus</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Landlord Name</strong> </td><td>$lName</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Landlord Phone</strong> </td><td>$lPhone</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><strong>Student</strong> </td><td>$student</td></tr>

                                <tr><td><strong>Spouse Name</strong> </td><td>$sName</td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </html>
            EOF;

            //end of message 

            // validate the variables ======================================================
                    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

            //    if (empty($_POST['name']) & empty($_POST['email']) & empty($_POST['address']) & empty($_POST['city']) & empty($_POST['state']) & empty($_POST['zip']) & empty($_POST['years']) & empty($_POST['hPhone']) & empty($_POST['altPhone']) & empty($_POST['dNumber']) & empty($_POST['dState']) & empty($_POST['hType']) & empty($_POST['hStatus']) & empty($_POST['student']))
            //        $errors = 'Field is required.';
                    if (empty($_POST['name']))
                            $errors['name'] = 'name is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['email']))
                            $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['address']))
                            $errors['address'] = 'Address is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['city']))
                            $errors['city'] = 'City is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['state']))
                            $errors['state'] = 'State is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['zip']))
                            $errors['state'] = 'Zip is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['years']))
                            $errors['years'] = 'Years at current address is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['hPhone']))
                            $errors['hPhone'] = 'Home phone is required.';

                    if (empty($_POST['dNumber']))
                            $errors['dNumber'] = 'Driver license number is required.';

                     if(empty($_POST['dState'])) 
                            $errors['dState'] = 'Driver license state is required.';

                    if ($_POST['hType']= "") 
                            $errors['hType'] = 'Home Type is required.';

                    if ($_POST['hStatus']= "")
                            $errors['hStatus'] = 'hStatus is required.';

                    if(empty($_POST['student'])) 
                            $errors['student'] = 'student? is required.';

            // return a response ===========================================================

                    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
                    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

                            // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
                            $data['success'] = false;
                            $data['errors']  = $errors;
                    } else {

                            // If there are no errors, send the email
                    if (!$errors) {
                            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                            echo "Message has been sent....!";
                    }
            }

                    // return all our data to an AJAX call
                    echo json_encode($data);
            ?>
```

Comment: If that's your actual code, it's your heredoc. You have spaces before `EOF;` closing identifier; remove them. Error reporting would have thrown you an error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "success.form.bv" event actually doesn't return any data, but only the event. You can check [here](http://formvalidation.io/settings/) at Form events section.

Accordingly to this documentation you can find the "data" this way:

```
$(e.target).data('bootstrapValidator').getInvalidFields()
```

I gave it a try in the console and it worked. Since it turned an empty array, I checked different methods and they returned exactly what expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'm not sure I am following completely however. Are you saying to change the line at 153 in the js file 
from: if (data.fv.getInvalidFields()     
to: if $(e.target).data('bootstrapValidator').getInvalidFields()          
If so... when I do that I get an error immediately that says Unexpected identifier on that line. You can check http://www.chelseaporter.com/APSoPC/adoptForm.php   to see the new error. 

Thanks so far!

Comment: You forgot to put the ( between if and $(..)

Comment: Thanks lecya! That fixed that issue! I'm no longer getting the data error. HOWEVER.. now to the next issue that has come up... The form pretends to submit, but never seems to trigger the ajax so the form doesn't actually get emailed. Basically it skips all the lines of code after line 162 of the javascript. Can you work your magic on that issue as well?? :)  This is where I feel I have some kind of redundancy or something wrong but I am lost.

Comment: you have to put the preventDefault event before all your code, inside the function =) that must be the first thing you call on submit, otherwise the normal submit from browser will trigger until you stop it =)

Comment: Not seeming to help so far. Maybe i'm doing it wrong? I copied the event.preventDefault(); from line 208 and moved it up to line 166 just below  $("#adoption-form").submit(function(event) {    but it doesn't seem to help. I have that preventdefault in there a few times. I also tried moving the one from line 157 up to line 153 and that didn't seem to help either :(

Comment: Actually it works. It enters your code and send the ajax request. Try to add .fail(function(data){console.log(data.responseText)}) right after the .done() in your ajax request. You will see an error from the server, which says that some data you send are required (address, city, ...). So your ajax request works fine, you are not sending all required information =)

Comment: I'm getting this... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .     it's not liking that new command with the period?

Comment: you wrote it wrong. It's .done(function(data) { your code here }).fail(function(data) { your code here });

Comment: OMG I THINK I GOT IT! I <3 you!!! You just saved my day. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!